# SQL Server : how to manage foreign key? When we need merge data from different locations?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I develop an inventory software in C# using Visual Studio 2017.

The Database used is SQL Server 2016. The software runs at different locations on local SQL Servers.

```
Server1                     server2              server3

Location A                Location B           Location C

   Db1                        Db2                 Db3

Customer                    Customer           Customer

CustId   Name           CustId   Name       CustId    Name
---------------         -----------------   -------------------
  1      John              1     Peter         1      Watson
```

For example, I have generated invoice 1001 from Server1, 1002 from Server2 and 1003 from Server 3 (all three invoice's `CustId` are 1 but name are different)

After merge above records to Location D are as below:

```
                   Db4 Location D           Customer Table 
              InvNo   InvId CustId          CustId  CustomerName   GUID
              1001      1        1              1       John        x      Server1 
              1002     21        1              1       Peter       x1     Server2
              1003     31        1              1       Watson      x2     Server3
```

`CustomerId` in `Invoice` table is a foreign key reference.

My problem is: the `Customer` table has three duplicate Id (1) for different names.

Suppose I used query to my software

```
select Customername, InvNo
from InvoiceMst
left join CustomerMst on CustomerMst.CustId = InvoiceMst.CustId
```

then it is wrong after the merge.

If I use CustomerName Instead of CustomerId as foreignKey then there is no problem. I can write query as

```
select Customername, InvNo
from InvoiceMst
left join CustomerMst on CustomerMst.CustomerNAME = InvoiceMst.CustomerName
```

so Is it right way to use CustomerName as foreign key? Or any other best option?

Thanks.

Comment: The fastest way to fix this is to redesign your tables to use GUID instead of INT as the CustomerId. Why? The GUID should not repeat and it is made for this situation. Then you can use the CustomerId as the foreign key as you should. If you use CustomerName it will break when you have more than one person with the same name. 

https://forums.asp.net/t/1899259.aspx?Using+a+Guid+uniqueidentifier+as+a+Primary+Key+in+SQL+Server

Comment: If its just 3 ids that are identical, why dont you fix them and add an auto increment to it? should have been there from the start if its a primary key

Comment: Thanks Montewhizdoh.  this is usefull. I will change my table structure. thanks again

Comment: The typical way to handle this would be to add a **LocationID** column to all relevant tables, and make the `(LocationId, CustomerId)` pair the primary key for the `Customer` table (and thus reference it from other tables by using both columns, too). Give each of your locations a unique `LocationID`, and your problems are solved